# How to convert to UTF-8 in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, nvarchar

I'm working on MSSQL server 2017.

I got table with a 'name' nvarchar column with values that look like '\u039b \u041e \u0422 \u0422 \u0410'

(sequence of '\u0[number][number][number or letter]')

how do I convert them to the correct characters?

Comment: hi again, what about string that looks like ''%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0''  ?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the same as JSON escaping.

You can use `JSON_VALUE` to get the value out, by creating a JSON array

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE('["' + t.name + '"]', '$[0]')
FROM YourTable t;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cfb28c75f1ec031df97febcda5961a4e)

Comment: thanks, i tried this and it gave the correct names for second and then the error message: "JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 66."

Comment: i found 1 wrong name which make it all to crush, now its working well!! thanks again @Charlieface